# C++ Eclipse says invalid arguments (type not correct)

Tags: c++, eclipse, warnings

The code is

```
g_CDioService->getDioPrjMgr()->NotifyBtMacAddress(std::string(path));
```

Declaration is

```
void NotifyBtMacAddress(const std::string &path);
```

Eclipse underlines `NotifyBtMacAddress` and says

```
Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void NotifyBtMacAddress(const ? &)'
```

I've even tried to explicitly cast it to the type actually expected:

```
g_CDioService->getDioPrjMgr()->NotifyBtMacAddress(const_cast<const std::string & >(std::string(path)));
```

But still gives the same (red underlined) error/warning.

I have access to the source of the function

```
void CDioPrjMgr::NotifyBtMacAddress(const std::string &path){

   // PASLOG(ZONE_FUNC, __FUNCTION__, "Sequence: PRJ_DIO -> PRJ_Manager : Send BT MAC ADdress");

    // On recving Disable BT command, Send Mac Addres to Mgr.
...
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly the code is fine. I want to know why eclipse thinks it's not.

Comment: You get that when you build the project or as you typing?

Comment: Did you define the method or is it from a library?

Comment: @gsamaras as I'm typing.

Comment: Try compiling. Share the Warnings/Errors please.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I defined it `void CDioPrjMgr::NotifyBtMacAddress(const std::string &path) {` ...

Comment: @OnurTuna it compiles fine. The issue is with Eclipse; this isn't a C++ question, just involves C++ code.

Comment: No any IDE is clever in the world. Don't let it get to you.

Comment: CODAN is not perfect. If the compiler says it's good, it's good. The compiler is god. Even when it's wrong, it might as well be right because you can't do smurf all without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDEs usually fail to resolve some things (for various reasons), but that *does not always mean that the code is wrong*.

So, just save the project or/and build it.

---

Another trick that sometimes works is: Project->Index->Rebuild to force Eclipse to take a good look at everything again - credits: user4581301

---

<sub>Since there is no minimal example here, we cannot reproduce what you are seeing.</sub>

Comment: I restarted Eclipse and magically, the underline was gone so it was an indexer issue. There's still lots of other functions with this red underline thing but it's probably the same indexer-related issue.

Comment: @Adrian another trick that sometimes works is Project->Index->Rebuild to force Eclipse to take a good look at everything again.

Comment: @user4581301 true, updated my question with your comment, OK?:)

Comment: @user4581301 alas, my code is so huge it gives 'out of memory' error after a few minutes of parsing it even after I increase Eclipse's heap area.

Comment: Crom! That should require an insane amount of code. You wouldn't happen to be including bits/stdc++.h and all of boost, would you?